# PDO Host Disregarded

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am setting up Symfony2 and, as part of the process, using the PDO extension for the first time. I got it setup alright, but I am having a problem specifying my hostname in the DSN. The MySQL host is on a different server and I am including that in the DSN (say "beta.example.com"). Yet the error message returned always says that there was an access denied response at the local server (say "alpha.example.com").

Just note: there is a MySQL server running local (on "alpha.example.com"), hence the access denied message, but the one I need to use is running on beta.example.com.

My DSN:

```
mysql:host=beta.example.com;port=3306;dbname=testdb;charset=UTF8
```

Here is a screenshot of the exact error attached (with hostnames modified to match my examples above):

https://skitch.com/nathanntg/gbrhx/pdo-exception

And it is not related to Symfony, it happens if I directly call the PDO creation from a blank PHP file:

```
<?
$a = new PDO('mysql:host=beta.example.com;port=3306;dbname=testdb;charset=UTF8', 'testuser', 'password');
?>

Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[28000] [1045]      Access denied for user 'testuser'@'alpha.example.com' (using password: YES)' in -:2
Stack trace:
#0 -(2): PDO->__construct('mysql:host=beta…', 'testuser', 'password')
#1 {main}
thrown in - on line 2
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: First thing I'd do is run "dig +short beta.example.com" from the server where the app is hosted, to verify that it actually resolves to the IP you think it does.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "Access denied" message is generated by the contacted MySQL server and does not (necessarily) reflect the DNS name you're using.

Make sure that `beta.example.com` resolves to the host you're using (with `host beta.example.com`). Also, the configuration on that MySQL server might be somehow messed up. If you log in to beta.example.com *from beta.example.com*, do you get the same error message?

You can find out what host is contacted by creating a packet trace (for example with [wireshark](http://wireshark.org/)). A simple alternative is temporarily stopping (or firewalling) the MySQL server on beta.example.com and seeing whether the error message changes.

Comment: Notice the `testuser` is **alpha**.example.com permissions, not **beta**.example.com.  Might check the permissions for the database to make sure `testuser` can connect from **alpha**.example.com as well.

Comment: It's worth noting that you can find the IP that `beta.example.com` resolves to *in PHP* with [`gethostbyname()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.gethostbyname.php). I have had instances where `host beta.example.com` resolves differently (the circumstances and causes of this are complicated and unlikely, but it is possible and worth checking).

Comment: Thanks everyone! I was able to debug it by monitoring packets. And @DaveRandom, thanks. I should have remembered that.

Comment: @phihag It was actually a problem with the server resolving incorrectly, as a couple comments suggested.