# PDO on Windows ignores host name and username when password is empty

Tags: php, mysql, windows, pdo, sellvana

I'm not sure if there's something wrong with my setups or this is a bug in PDO on Windows:

```
<?php 

$dsn = 'mysql:host=127.0.0.1;dbname=mydb;charset=UTF8';
$username = 'myuser';
$password = '';
$pdo = new PDO($dsn, $username, $password);
```

Errors out for me with:

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message
>   'SQLSTATE[42000] [1044] Access denied for user ''@'localhost' to
>   database 'mydb'' in C:\Ampps\www\test.php:6 Stack trace: #0
>   C:\Ampps\www\test.php(6): PDO->__construct('mysql:host=127....',
>   'myuser', '') #1 {main} thrown in C:\Ampps\www\test.php on line 6

I've been able to reproduce this on all 3 of my Windows dev machines, but on none of the linux servers.

Can anyone confirm, or point out what could be a problem?

Thank you!

EDIT: The privileges are set correctly on the user with empty password.

EDIT2: There was a report that the issue is reproducible on Mac running MAMP 3.0.3

EDIT3: There were couple of reports before, but it looks like it hasn't been fixed yet:

https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=43493

https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=46457

My report: https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=67026

EDIT4: It works when the permissions are given to 'myuser'@'localhost', but the problem appears when permissions are given to 'myuser'@'%' without password - on linux as well

Comment: I can confirm this on my machine. Empty password -> `Access denied for user ''@'localhost' to database 'mydb''`, with password -> `Access denied for user 'myuser'@'localhost' (using password: YES)'`. Are you still able to connect if you supply the correct credentials?

Comment: @DaveChen yes, I'm able to connect with correct credentials

Comment: Does the same thing occur when you use an existing username? Such as, `$username = 'pma';`? (For xampp, but like use root with an empty password when root does have a password set)

Comment: @DaveChen even with correct user which has empty password, it gives the same error. It's not only about username, but also host is replaced with 'localhost', tried different hosts.

Comment: It looks like host is unrelated issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7787369/pdo-host-disregarded?rq=1

Comment: It looks like only username 'root' will work correctly without password. Any other username will result in error.

Comment: I can't get exactly what is your problem.

Comment: @YourCommonSense on setup where db user with proper privileges has empty password the connection can't be established, and the error shows that username is empty as well.

Comment: It simply can't be. You have to set up a user and give him proper permissions,

Comment: @YourCommonSense it can be if it's a bug :) There are correct permissions on the test user with empty password. did you try it?

Comment: ok i hope my last reply to you, because it's obvious to everybody else: how can i simplify my example?

Comment: I'd rather make it more complex. As one you posted so far is not an example at all, but rather groundless statement. The key word is "reproduceable". Means all the steps described which one can follow to reproduce the error.

Comment: Well, your report would be declined as "bogus". Because you failed to follow my advise

Comment: @Unirgy Wait, `The privileges are set correctly on the user with empty password.` Which user? If it's `myuser` then you should be able to login fine. Is `myuser` a valid user?

Comment: @DaveChen Yes, `myuser` is a valid user with correct permissions for `mydb`. I've rechecked it again now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is not with PHP or PDO, I was able to reproduce the issue directly with MySQL.

If there's ''@'localhost' user, can login with any username without password, and any users @'%' will be ignored on login.

Steps for reproduction: https://gist.github.com/sellvana/9989227

Answer (score 2):

I'd like to confirm this.

Please make sure the conditions are met before testing this:

1. Make sure nonexistent_user is not a user in the database.
2. Make sure root has a password set.
3. Make sure to run these tests separately.
4. Make sure to run these tests on Windows (or whatever machine affected).

I have bolded the usernames in question.

### Test #1

User that does not exist + empty password = empty username for error message

```
$mysqli = new Mysqli('localhost', 'nonexistent_user', '', 'database');
$pdo    = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=database;charset=UTF8', 'nonexistent_user', '');
```

> Warning: mysqli::mysqli(): (HY000/1044): Access denied for user **''@'localhost'** to database 'database' in test.php
>
> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY000] [1044] Access denied for user **''@'localhost'** to database 'database'' in test.php Stack trace: #0 test.php(): PDO->__construct('mysql:host=loca...', 'nonexistent_use...', '') #1 {main} thrown in test.php

### Test #2

User that exists + empty password = username set for error message

```
$mysqli = new Mysqli('localhost', 'root', '', 'database');
$pdo    = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=database;charset=UTF8', 'root', '');
```

> Warning: mysqli::mysqli(): (HY000/1045): Access denied for user **'root'@'localhost'** (using password: NO) in test.php
>
> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user **'root'@'localhost'** (using password: NO)' in test.php Stack trace: #0 test.php(): PDO->__construct('mysql:host=loca...', 'root', '') #1 {main} thrown in test.php

### Test #3

User that does not exist + set password = username set for error message

```
$mysqli = new Mysqli('localhost', 'nonexistent_user', 'password', 'database');
$pdo    = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=database;charset=UTF8', 'nonexistent_user', 'password');
```

> Warning: mysqli::mysqli(): (HY000/1045): Access denied for user **'nonexistent_user'@'localhost'** (using password: YES) in test.php
>
> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user **'nonexistent_user'@'localhost'** (using password: YES)' in test.php Stack trace: #0 test.php(): PDO->__construct('mysql:host=loca...', 'nonexistent_use...', 'password') #1 {main} thrown in test.php

When the user does not exists and an empty password is supplied, the error message will show a blank username.

I feel this would be a security risk because an attacker could potentially test which users are valid by sending a test username with an empty password and see if the error response is empty for the username or not.

Comment: Did you try with user that exists but with username different from 'root'?

Comment: It acts in the same way as test #2, it shows the username. `Access denied for user 'pma'@'localhost' to database 'database'` For me, the error would occur when I used a user that did not exist and an empty password.

Comment: @YourCommonSense On a website, I wouldn't want my users to see the usernames of all the other users. That's why when providing an error message, it's best to use a generic one such as `Your username or password is invalid.`, thus people can't test if the username exists or not. However, in this situation, if people are able to test for usernames, I feel that in itself would be a security risk.

Comment: okay okay i see. surely a big deal. I haven't used shared hosts for a decade, so, grew unaccustomed with this dormitory-style access

Comment: It seems that only test #2 is relevant to the OP, yet it rather brings results that are different. So, I don't understand what you really confirmed here

Comment: @YourCommonSense Test #1 shows a blank username in its error message. The other tests show instances where the username isn't blank. I might have tested out a different scenario than the OP, but I believe there is an issue with the error message provided. Do you think there is a problem with the error messages showing an empty username?

Comment: Test #1 contradicts with the OP, as he tests with existent user (as he thinks).

Comment: Speaking of problems - honestly, I don't fink there is one at all

Comment: -1 for this answer seems irrelevant to the question.

Comment: @DaveChen if you think it's a problem you'd rather ask another question. Site rules are quite clear on the matter of asking questions in the answers. Your question is most suitable for the security@SE for they are all paranoids there and would like to feast on this "bug"

Comment: Sorry for being off-topic. I truly believe this is an issue, and think that it should be fixed.

Comment: Well go on write to Oracle if you think so.

Comment: @YourCommonSense I initially thought this was the issue of the database as well. I imagine this error occurs in windows simply because the versions we have are outdated perhaps and the builds we have on linux have been newly setup. I'll do a quick update on my part and see what I find.

Comment: @DaveChen I've specifically downloaded latest 5.5.11 right now to test, and able to reproduce the same issue

Comment: @DaveChen There is NO error. There are only your speculations on some minor issue which is irrelevant to either windows or PHP at all.

Comment: @YourCommonSense I agree. It's not the fault of windows or PHP. However, there is a minor issue with the error message.

Comment: @DaveChen are you giving permissions to myuser@localhost? can you try 'myuser'@'%' instead (don't forget to remove myuser@localhost) ?

Comment: I was able to reproduce this issue on linux as well with myuser@% without password